# Why has Haskell decided against using `+` for string (list) concatenation?

Tags: haskell

Since I had trouble googling this question I thought I'd post it here.

I'm just interested in the logic behind it or wether it's just the creators' preference to use `++` instead. I mean, using a typeclass for strings that concatenates two strings (or rather lists) with `+` does not seem too hard to imagine.

**Edit:** I should add, that in Haskell one has to suspect reasons behind it, because `+` and `++` are functions defined in typeclasses, whereas in java the usage of `+` for string concatenation is just part of the language's syntax and therefor subject only to the creators preference/opinion. (The answers so far suggest that I was right about my suspicion.)

Also haskell comes from a mathematical background and is deeply influenced by mathematical syntax, so there might be deeper reasons than just preference/opinion.

Comment: Because `(+)` is just a function, and it is part of the `Num` typeclass. A string is *not* a number.

Comment: My guess on why `(+)` is defined in the `Num` typeclass and not as part of the `Monoid` typeclass (and have `Num` as a subclass of `Monoid`) is probably historic, since `Monoid` was introduced after `Num`, and also because there's 2 `Monoid` instances for numeric types.

Comment: Even then, why should `(+)` be the *monoid* operator, as opposed to the operator for some other group-like structure? `Num` is far from being part of a mathematically rigourous hierarchy, and in the end `(+)` is used for the things most likely to be similar to integer addition. List concatenation (being a familiar operation but lacking commutativity or an inverse) is far enough from that definition to warrant its own operator.

Comment: You might also look at [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Classification_by_properties) and ask yourself which object has the best claim on using `(+)` for its operation. (`Num` isn't so much one of those objects as it is "a bunch of stuff that is pretty much the same for integers, rationals, reals, and complex numbers".)

Comment: Closely related: [*Why is the \`mappend\` infix alias \`<>\` instead of \`+\`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23794894/2751851)

Comment: Haskell predates the ridiculous popularity of `+` for string concatenation.  Concatenating strings is nothing like addition, so using different operators is sensible.

Comment: I do not have the feeling that this is a primary opinion base question (or at least the answers are really technically justified) , and so I do not thing this question shoud be put on hold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, it would cause type troubles.

`(+)` is part of the `Num` typeclass:

```
class  Num a  where
    (+), (-), (*)       :: a -> a -> a
    negate              :: a -> a
    abs                 :: a -> a
    signum              :: a -> a
    fromInteger         :: Integer -> a

    x - y               = x + negate y
    negate x            = 0 - x
```

And `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

It's easy to see the first problem: if we wanted `(+)` to work on list, we would have to implement `(*)`, `negate`, `abs`, `signum`, and `fromInteger` for lists as well. Which is spurious.

If we decided to seperate `(+)` from the typeclass, and make a new typeclass, maybe called `Plussable` for `(+)`, there would be too many typeclasses to keep track of, and simple expressions like `1 + 2*(2-1)` would no longer be of type `Num a => a`, it would be of type `(Plussable a, Timesable a, Minusable a) => a`, and so on for each operation. It would be far too complicated.

Comment: That last argument is not per se correct. We could make a `Class (Plussable a, Timesable a) => Num a where ...`, to group typeclasses together.

Comment: That's true, but we would have to write the type explicitly rather than having it inferred as it currently is. Or compiler magic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You could declare it with that type, but it wouldn't be inferred anymore

Comment: You can, in fact, express `1 + 2*(2-1)` using a single type class, but it does, indeed, require much verbosity: `Sum 1 <> (Sum $ getProduct $ Product 2 <> (Product $ getSum $ Sum 2 <> Sum (-1)))`. The type class in question is `Monoid`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann A single class, *maybe*... but not a single constraint.

Comment: @MarkSeemann actually, since `Sum a` and `Product a` are both instances of `Num`, we can reduce your expression to `getSum $ 1 <> (getProduct $ 2 <> (getSum $ 2 <> (-1)))`. This however relies on the fact that integral numerals are polymorphic with type `Num a => a`.

Comment: @M.Aroosi Ooh, I didn't know that! Very cool! Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 16):

> typeclass for strings that concatenates two strings

Such a typeclass exists, although the operator isn't `+`, but `<>`:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Monoid
Prelude Data.Monoid> "foo" <> "bar"
"foobar"
```

While `++` concatenates lists, the `<>` operator is more general, since it combines any two values of a given `Monoid` instance.

As other people have pointed out, `+` is reserved for `Num` instances. Why isn't the `Monoid` binary operator called `+`, then? Because addition is only one of infinitely many monoids; multiplication is another:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> Sum 2 <> Sum 3
Sum {getSum = 5}
Prelude Data.Monoid> Product 2 <> Product 3
Product {getProduct = 6}
```

Choosing something like `<>` as 'the' monoidal operator is preferred exactly because it carries little semantic baggage.

Comment: Although it's true that there are infinitely many monoids, sum and product are that only natural ones for numbers.